# Flutter: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)

Tags: flutter, video-player

I am trying to play a network video for that i am using chewie: ^1.4.0 and video_player: ^2.6.1 package. when i use this [video link](https://server.appsstaging.com:3091/uploads/moduleImage/2023-06-13T08-33-03.541ZY2Mate.is%20-%20This%20crab%20is%20so%20fun%20Useful%20Baby%20Product%20&%20Toys%201213--nUnAkXniYU-720p-1658960279583.mp4) it throws this error

```
PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)
```

here is my code:

```
  late VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
  ChewieController? chewieController;
```

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initPlayer();
  }
```

```
  void _initPlayer() {
    videoPlayerController =
        VideoPlayerController.network("https://server.appsstaging.com:3091/uploads/moduleImage/2023-06-13T08-33-03.541ZY2Mate.is%20-%20This%20crab%20is%20so%20fun%20Useful%20Baby%20Product%20&%20Toys%201213--nUnAkXniYU-720p-1658960279583.mp4")
          ..initialize().then((value) => setState(() {}));

    chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
      autoPlay: false,
      looping: false,
      zoomAndPan: true,
      deviceOrientationsAfterFullScreen: DeviceOrientation.values,
    );
    setState(() {});
  }
```

displaying video player like this

```
Container(
              child: Chewie(
                controller: chewieController!,
              ),
            )
         
    )
```

kindly help where i am doing wrong, how to resolve it. thanks